# Шифр многоалфавитной одноконтурной обыкновенной подстановки

Tags: python

Есть вот такая вот программа, шифрующее предложение на русском языке, заменяя символы алфавита на символы трёх других алфавитов. Однако при расшифровке предложения возникают проблемы: расшифровка в некотором месте может пойти не так(При наличии прочих символов(не букв(пробелы и знаки препинания))), буквы следующие после этих прочих символов пропадают и не идут в окончательный ответ.

```
print("Будем шифровать или расшифровывать? cif/decif")
cipher=input()
print("Введите, пожалуйста, ваше предложение: ")
text=input()
 
alphabet = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
alphabet1 = ['ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я','а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё']
alphabet2 = ['о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','ы','ь','э','ю','я','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
alphabet3 = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m','<','>','@','%','Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','{','}','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M','+','*','&','$']
gamma = '" ".,:;`\|/()!?№^-=_'
 
def cryp(t):
    z = 0
    ret = []
    for x in text:
        if x in alphabet:
            if (z%3)==0:
                id = alphabet.index(x)
                ret += alphabet1[id]
            elif (z%3)==1:
                id = alphabet.index(x)
                ret += alphabet2[id]
            elif (z%3)==2:
                id = alphabet.index(x)
                ret += alphabet3[id]
            z = z+1
        elif x.isalpha() == False:
            ret.append(gamma[(gamma.find(x)+z)%len(gamma)])
        else:
            ret += x
    sret = ''.join(ret)
    return sret
 
def encreep(t):
    z = 0
    y = 0
    ret = []
    for x in text:
        z = z+1
    while y!=z:
        for x in text:
            if (y%3)==0:
                if x in alphabet1:
                    id = alphabet1.index(x)
                    ret += alphabet[id]
                    y=y+1
                elif x.isalpha() == False:
                    ret.append(gamma[(gamma.find(x)-y)%len(gamma)])
                    y=y+1
            elif (y%3)==1:
                if x in alphabet2:
                    id = alphabet2.index(x)
                    ret += alphabet[id]
                    y=y+1
                elif x.isalpha() == False:                                        #
                    ret.append(gamma[(gamma.find(x)-y)%len(gamma)])               #
                    y=y+1                                                         #
            elif (y%3)==2:
                if x in alphabet3:
                    id = alphabet3.index(x)
                    ret += alphabet[id]
                    y=y+1
                elif x.isalpha() == False:
                    ret.append(gamma[(gamma.find(x)-y)%len(gamma)])
                    y=y+1
            else:
                ret += x
        sret = ''.join(ret)
        return sret
 
if cipher == "cif":
    print(cryp(text))
elif cipher == "decif":
    print(encreep(text))
else:
    print("Прошу прощения, но, видимо, где-то ошибка. Надеюсь, вы правильно всё написали. Приношу извинения за сбой!")
```

Comment: у вас gamma состоит из двух строк (gamma = '' '.,:;`\|/()!?№^-=_')... так и должно быть? попробуйте gamma = '" ".,:;`\|/()!?№^-=_'

Comment: Спасибо, Jack_oS, решилась проблема с пробелами! Но, к сожалению, некоторые символы продолжают пропадать. Так, например,  при шифровке предложения: "папа и мама" выводит "цоgж:ч;sжаq". А при расшифровка этого предложения выводит "папа  ама"(с двумя пробелами)